# Azure Cloud Service Error while running(F5) project

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net

I'm trying to run and debug Azure Cloud Service project which works fine when I deploy it on Azure Cloud but when i try to run in within Visual Studio for debug/emulator it is throwing me this error.

> Error 7   unable to get setting value Parameter name: profileName

PS: I'm using visual studio 2013 with Azure SDK 2.7. It builds without any error. This is getting very critical because I need to upload 500 mb of data every single time I update my code. Can someone please guide me what I'm missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the service configuration file called ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg or you'll encounter this precise error.

Let me know if this fix your issue.

Comment: Renamed the Local service configuration to XXX.Local and had this issue. When I put back the name to Local all went back to normal. Thx for the hint buddy.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to the renaming of default cloud service configurations. In general you have ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg and ServiceConfiguration.local.cscfg. If you rename them there might be some reference to it left in the project settings.
Check the following to get rid of the error:
- Clean solution
- Check the service role configuration that no invalid configuration is selected
- Check the project properties of the implementation project, for invalid references
- Check the build configurations of your project

Comment: I cleaned up everything, even opened up the ccproj and looked for references.  Still didn't work.  It was only when I renamed my ServiceConfiguration.Development.cscfg back to ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg that it started to work again.  It looks to me like something is baked into Visual Studio that only looks for that configuration.  Are you sure you didn't have a zombie version of the 'local' file still hanging around?